# Maclaurin's Series of Quotients and Products

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

As we all (should) know, the Maclaurin series is a special case of the Taylor series when the Taylor series is centered around 0. This is the canonical definition of the Maclaurin series:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n
$$

My question is this. Should it be that:

$$
\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = {\dfrac{\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}{\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}}x^n}{\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}{\dfrac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}}x^n}}
$$

or that:

$$
\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\dfrac{\dfrac{d^{(n)}}{d^{(n)}x}{\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}}}{n!}}x^n
$$

Intuitively speaking, I find the former equation much more appealing, not only because it **seems** logical, but also because the latter equation would be much much harder to solve for quotients.

The same question applies to products.

Comment: Both can be hard. Division of power series (assuming say $g(0)\ne 0$) is feasible for obtaining the first few terms, but general expression will often not be accessible. Already $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ poses difficulties.

Comment: I should point out that you've only stated the _coefficients_ of the Maclaurin series. For it to make sense you need to multiply each coefficient by $x^n$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that! I missed it out.